# Parsing XML from websites and save the code?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.5

I would like to parse the xml code from a website like 
http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/docdb/EP1000000/biblio
and save it in another xml or csv file.

I tried it with this:

```
import urllib.request 
web_data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/docdb/EP1000000/biblio")
str_data = web_data.read()
try:
   f = open("file.xml", "w")
   f.write(str(str_data))
   print("SUCCESS")
except:
   print("ERROR")
```

But in the saved XML data is between every element '\n' and at the beginning ' b' '

How can i save the XML data without all the 'n\' and ' b' '?

Comment: If your `str_data` is in fact a string, have you tried simply doing a replace for the specific characters you don't want?

Comment: in Python 3 `read()` gives `bytes` and you have to use `decode()` to convert it to string/unicode - you can't use `str()`. Or better open file as `'wb'` and write data without `str()` - `f.write(str_data)`

Answer (score 1):

If you write the xml file in binary mode, you don't need to convert the data read into a string of characters first. Also, if you process the data a line at a time, that should get rid of `'\n'` problem. The logic of your code could also be structured a little better IMO, as shown below:

```
import urllib.request

web_data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services"
                                  "/published-data/publication"
                                  "/docdb/EP1000000/biblio")
data = web_data.read()
with open("file.xml", "wb") as f:
    for line in data:
        try:
            f.write(data)
        except Exception as exc:
            print('ERROR')
            print(str(exc))
            break
    else:
        print('SUCCESS')
```

Answer (score 0):

`read()` returns data as `bytes` but you can save data without converting to `str()`. You have to open file in `byte` mode - `"wb"` - and write data.

```
import urllib.request

web_data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/docdb/EP1000000/biblio")
data = web_data.read()

try:
   f = open("file.xml", "wb")
   f.write(data)
   print("SUCCESS")
except:
   print("ERROR")
```

BTW: To convert `bytes` to `string/unicode` you have to use ie. `decode('utf-8')` .
If you use `str()` then Python uses own method to create string and it adds `b"` to inform you that you have `bytes` in your `data`.